# MongoDB and Apache Mahout Connection Error

Tags: java, mongodb, maven, mahout, mongodb-java

Trying to Connect Apache Mahout to a Mongo DB. However when I run it I get the following error. Not Sure what's wrong. I have Also made sure that the MongoClient Library connects.

Error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.DBCollection.ensureIndex(Lcom/mongodb/DBObject;)V

    at org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.model.mongodb.MongoDBDataModel.buildModel(MongoDBDataModel.java:559)
    at org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.model.mongodb.MongoDBDataModel.<init>(MongoDBDataModel.java:243)
    at util.Connection.connectToServer(Connection.java:23)
```

Method:

```
public MongoDatabase connectToServer() throws MongoSocketException, UnknownHostException {


        //Working
        MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI("mongodb://localhost:27017");

            MongoClient mongoDB = new MongoClient(uri);
            MongoDatabase mongoConnection = mongoDB.getDatabase("loka");

        //Throws Error
            MongoDBDataModel dbm = new MongoDBDataModel("127.0.0.1",27017,"loka","BEACON_LOOKUP",true,false,null);

            return mongoConnection;
    }
```

POM Dependancies:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.mahout</groupId>
            <artifactId>mahout-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.mahout</groupId>
            <artifactId>mahout-math</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.mahout</groupId>
            <artifactId>mahout-collections</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.mahout</groupId>
            <artifactId>mahout-integration</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no expert of Mahout nor Java. But the error message does look like you are using an incompatible version of MongoDB Java Driver.

Note that there are 2 branches of MongoDB Java Driver:

1. 2.x maintains old driver from before.
2. To support async and new MongoDB features there's 3.x branch.

The 3.x branch is not backward compatible. Methods like `ensureIndex` are changed to `createIndex` for example. There are bunch of other changes too.
So back to your question, I think you should try latest 2.x branch, which is 2.14 by now.

To check compatibility between Java Driver and MongoDB version, read the [document](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/java/#mongodb-compatibility).